# Raw links are hyperlinked differently between the live preview and the rendered post

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, editor

In the live preview, a raw hyperlink is hyperlinked if it is prefaced with a whitespace or a punctuation character.
In the rendered post, a raw hyperlink is hyperlinked only if prefaced with a whitespace, not a punctuation.

[Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398442/147640):

```
Code：https://github.com/  
Code: https://github.com/  
Code - https://github.com/  
Code!https://github.com/  
Code.https://github.com/  
Codehttps://github.com/
```

Result:

Code：https://github.com/
Code: https://github.com/
Code - https://github.com/
Code!https://github.com/
Code.https://github.com/
Codehttps://github.com/

Picture of the live preview:

> [image]

Picture of the rendered post:

> [image]

Comment: What's that cursed colon in the first line?

Comment: @Cerbrus It's a Fullwidth Colon/U+FF1A.

Comment: Looking at the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls), Urls should be surrounded by whitespace to be automatically formatted. So, the rendered output is correct. The preview is just a little too eager...

Comment: Gotta say... I'm glad it is just a wonky unicode character and not the image that was invoked in my brain when I read "cursed colon".